# Syntax to SSH with local .PEM file on Win 10

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, virtual-machine

I've never SSH'd before, and have created a linux VM on azure (Ubuntu 18.04).  I have enabled SSH access (port 22) to the server but I'm unable to connect to it.  Azure helped me create the keys, and I have a .pem file on my local system, sitting on my win 10 desktop.

Opening a command prompt with administator rights, I'm attempting the following:

```
ssh MyUserName@99.99.99.9 -i C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MySSHFolder\MyPrivateKeyStuff.pem
```

Obviously, I've modified the actual specific values for security, but the overall syntax is what I've attempted. When I use the stmt above, my command window locks for a few seconds, and returns:

```
ssh: connect to host 99.99.99.9 port 22: Connection timed out
```

What could be going on?  Do I have something obviously wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check first the Azure Filewall: from [the FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-faq#does-azure-firewall-support-inbound-traffic-filtering)

> Azure Firewall supports inbound and outbound filtering. Inbound protection is typically used for non-HTTP/S protocols.
> For example RDP, SSH, and FTP protocols.
>
> For best inbound HTTP/S protection, use a web application firewall such as Azure [Web Application Firewall (WAF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/overview).

With a WAF in place, you can check the [firewall logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-diagnostics), and see if your connection goes through.